# Both Cython and Numba, Pandasql sqldf select statement throws sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, cython, numba, pandasql

I am really new to Python programming. I have a dataframe pandasql query which runs fine when I run my code with the standard Python3 implementation. **However, after cythonizing it**, I always get the following exception:

**sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: dataf**

Following is the snippet from the processor.pyx file

```
import pandas as pd
from pandasql import sqldf

    def process_date(json):
        #json has the properties format [{"x": "1", "y": "2", "z": "3"}]
        dataf = pd.read_json(json, orient='records')
        sql = """select x, y, z from dataf;"""
        result = sqldf(sql)
```

**Could cythonizing the code make it behave differently? This exact same code runs
fine with the standard python3 implementation.**
Following is the setup.py I have written to transpile the code to c.

```
# several files with ext .pyx, that i will call by their name
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules=[
    Extension("c_processor",     ["processor.pyx"])]

setup(
  name = 'RTP_Cython',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules,
)
```

**I also tried to use Numba and got the same error**. Code below:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandasql import sqldf
from numba import jit
from numpy import arange

@jit
def process_data():
        print("In process data")
        json = "[{\"id\": 2, \"name\": \"zain\"}]"
        df = pd.read_json(json, orient='records')
        sql = "select id, name from df;"
        df = sqldf(sql)
        print("the df is %s" % df)
process_data()
```

If I comment out @jit annotation, the code works fine.
Should I be using another extension of the panda libraries that inter operate with C, since both Numba and Cython give me the same error?
I hope there is an easy solution to this.

Comment: does `sqldf(sql, { 'dataf': dataf })` work? My guess is that `locals()` or `globals()` are not passed to `sqldf` in the same way in case of cython.

Comment: thanks a lot J.J. ! looks like this did the trick. But I am still not sure why passing this option would make a difference in a cython/numba approach.

Comment: It looks like pandasql tries to inspect the Python stack to find missing variables. I wouldn't expect this to work on either Cython or numba. Relying on this sort of trick looks like a pretty awful design to me - if you want to use variables in a function then you should pass the variables to the function.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I inherited a bunch of code that is doing some pandas dataframe operations. I have to make this code run faster. The dataframe has only 1 record. I was assuming that cythonizing it would enhance the performance. Do you think it would be a good idea to replace pandas with numPy if the record size in the pandas dataframe is less?If I just use numPy instead of pandas, I could then boost performance with Numba/Cython?

Comment: To optimize your code, you must first know where the most time is spent in your code, I would recommend you first profile your application and then check what should be optimized first. See this link for more informations: https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html